# Magento Website or Magento Store?

Tags: stores, websites, multi-website

We have a business requirement wherein, a collections of products will use "shipping method A" and a "payment method A". While a certain other collection of products will follow "shipping method B" and "payment method B".

In order to prevent buyer from adding products from both the collection to a cart together, we are evaluating creating a new website (or a store).  This would be to ensure that products from both the stores do not show together.

Other than shipping and payment, the list of extensions for the second shop are also very different from the first shop.

What would be the best option for achieving this functionality ? Should we set up a new website or just a new store for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per opinion, You should create a separate website with own store.

Because.... When you create a product you assign it on website level not on store level

So, 2 different website will work for you.

Comment: Thanks ! Can we use different set of extensions for different websites ?

Comment: There will be same extension for both website, but you can enable/disable on website level Or can change settings!

Answer (score 1):

As per your need,

1.You need to create multiple website from your Magento 2

from here....

**On the Admin panel, click Stores. In the Settings section, select All Stores**

2.as per your need create the product for particular website.

3.And the other thing is shipping method and payment method that was also set as per the website.

just got For this, go to the **Admin Panel> Stores> Configuration** and there top right select the website as per your need and configure the payment method enable and disable as per your website.

payments Method and shipping method configuration are available into the sales tab.
you can change configuration as per your need.